# MKMapView covering SKSpriteNodes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, mapkit, skscene

I am experimenting with using `MapKit` and `SpriteKit` together, but I have hit a pretty major wall.

I have my map set up in my `GameScene` because I don't want the scene covering it, however when I attempt to add a `SpriteNode` to the view, it doesn't show. Upon reducing the map's alpha, I can see that the sprites are being rendered underneath the map.
Changing `zPosition` hasn't helped, as I'm assuming views such as `MKMapView`s are on a separate layer from `SpriteKit` objects.

Essentially what I am trying to accomplish is putting `SpriteKit` elements over top of my `MKMapView` (if possible, without storyboards - I am trying to do everything programmatically). I have spent hours trying to find an answer on the Internet but was unsuccessful.

Here is my `GameScene`:

```
    import UIKit
    import SpriteKit
    import GameplayKit
    import MapKit
    import CoreLocation

    class GameScene: SKScene, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

        var map = MKMapView()

        let healthBar = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Square")
        let maxHealthBar = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Square")

        var UID = String()
        var ref = DatabaseReference()

        static var username = String()
        static var health = Int()
        static var maxHealth = Int()

        var width = CGFloat()
        var right = CGFloat()
        var left = CGFloat()
        var top = CGFloat()
        var bot = CGFloat()
        var margin = CGFloat()
        var middleX = CGFloat()
        var middleY = CGFloat()

        var maxBarWidth = CGFloat()

        override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

            map.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)
            map.delegate = self
            map.showsScale = false
            map.showsPointsOfInterest = false
            map.showsUserLocation = true
            map.showsBuildings = true
            map.isZoomEnabled = false
            map.isScrollEnabled = false
            map.isPitchEnabled = false
            map.isRotateEnabled = false

            let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance((locationManager.location?.coordinate)!, 400, 400)

            map.setRegion(region, animated: false)

            print("region:", map.region)

            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

            if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()) {

                locationManager.delegate = self
                locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
                locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

            }

            view.addSubview(map)

            width = frame.width
            right = frame.width
            left = frame.width - frame.width
            top = frame.height
            bot = frame.height - frame.height
            margin = frame.width / 75
            middleX = frame.width / 2
            middleY = frame.height / 2

            maxBarWidth = width - margin * 2
            let maxBarHeight = CGFloat(30)
            let healthBarWidth = width - margin * 2
            let barHeight = maxBarHeight * 0.75

            maxHealthBar.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
            maxHealthBar.position = CGPoint(x: middleX, y: top - margin - maxBarHeight / 2)
            maxHealthBar.size = CGSize(width: maxBarWidth, height: maxBarHeight)
            maxHealthBar.color = UIColor.black
            maxHealthBar.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
            maxHealthBar.zPosition = 1.1
            self.addChild(maxHealthBar)

            healthBar.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
            healthBar.position = CGPoint(x: middleX - healthBarWidth / 2, y: maxHealthBar.position.y)
            healthBar.size = CGSize(width: healthBarWidth, height: barHeight)
            healthBar.color = UIColor.red
            healthBar.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
            healthBar.zPosition = 1000000
            self.addChild(healthBar)

            print("parent", healthBar.parent)

        }

        override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
            for t in touches {
                let location = t.location(in: self)

                takeDamage(damage: 10)

            }
        }

        func takeDamage(damage: Int) {

            GameScene.health -= damage

            updateHealth()

        }

        func updateHealth() {

            let percentFull = CGFloat(GameScene.health / GameScene.maxHealth)
            let healthWidth = maxBarWidth * percentFull

            healthBar.size.width = healthWidth

        }

        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
            map.setCenter((locationManager.location?.coordinate)!, animated: true)
        }

        override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
            // Called before each frame is rendered
        }
    }
```

And here is my `GameViewController`:

```
    import UIKit
    import SpriteKit
    import GameplayKit

    class GameViewController: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        }

        override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
            super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

            if (SignInScene.signInLoaded == false) {

                if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
                    // Configure the view.
                    let skView = self.view as! SKView
                    skView.showsFPS = true
                    skView.showsNodeCount = true

                    /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
                    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

                    /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
                    scene.size = skView.bounds.size
                    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                    skView.presentScene(scene)
                }

            }

        }

        override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
            return false
        }

        override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
            if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
                return .portrait
            } else {
                return .portrait
            }
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }

        override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
            return false
        }
    }
```

I am extremely stuck on this one and would greatly appreciate any help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You really should try keeping design and code separated, if you make a habit out of it in your little projects, you will find it to be a lot easier on yourself when you end up designing larger applications.  Plus when asking for help on places like SO, it becomes less code to show, which means others will be able to help you out better.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is your UIView heirarchy in your view controller,

Here is what your project looks like:

> Controller
>   --SKView
>   ----SKScene
>   --MKMapView

You need to change your hierarchy to be

> Controller
>   --MKMapView
>   --SKView
>   ----SKSceneView

I would recommend doing this inside your storyboard, so that you can keep design and code separated.

After you have changed your hierarchy, you need to do the following in your GameScene:

```
view.allowsTransparency = true
view.backgroundColor = .clear
backgroundColor = .clear
```

This will give you a view and scene that has no background color, which means that your map will show underneath it.

Now if you want touch events to hit the `MKMapView` and not the `SKView`,  then you need to disable `userInteractionEnabled` on your `MKMapView`, or pass the touch events to the map from your `SKView`.

Comment: This is probably a simple question, but I haven't used storyboards a whole lot...how would I get an SKView/SKSceneView in the storyboard?

Comment: You already have one if you used the default template.  They make it for you

Comment: The one called view? If I try to follow the hierarchy you suggested above and add the map view as a child of the GameViewController, it deletes all its other children? Am I putting it in the wrong place?

Comment: SKView is just UiView with custom class SKView.  You can copy the UIView into your clip board, put the mapview on, the. Paste the view

Comment: I copied and pasted the view, but it doesn't let me set it as a child of GameViewController. It's putting it as a separate interface on top of the map view. My storyboard now looks like there are 2 phones (I hope that makes sense)...is that a problem?

Comment: I have been trying to set both the MapView and the SKView as children of the GameViewController, but it won't let me. It will only take one, and it puts the other as a child of GameViewControllerScene. If I put the SKView under GameViewController, it doesn't show the map, and if I put the MapView as the child, it crashes/doesn't start properly. @Knight0fDragon

Comment: I dont know why you are getting confused, you want the skview to be the child of map view

Comment: It wont let me. I try to add the SKView as a child of the MapView, but it replaces the MapView instead...then I try it the other way around and it does the same thing - the SKView gets replace @Knight0fDragon

Comment: Are you dragging onto the edit view or the tree view? Drop it on the edit view

Comment: I've tried both, I get the same issue. Instead of setting the previous one as its parent, it replaces it. It does however allow me to set a normal UIView as a child of the SKView, not sure if that could help? @Knight0fDragon

Comment: I dont know what to tell you, I dont know why you are having a problem.  Try finding a tutorial on how to use the interface builder so you can see what you are doing wrong

Comment: Are you sure the hierarchy should be: `Game View Controller Scene > Game View Controller > MKMapView > SKView`? @Knight0fDragon

Comment: Yes i am absolutely positive,  you may need to have a parent UIVew because MapView may not allow children in IB (even though it can have children)

Comment: I tried that, still no luck. No matter what I do, it will not let me add a child to the MapView. @Knight0fDragon

Comment: No, you make both a child of the uiview and still follow the heirarchy

Comment: Ok...that I can do. Do I need to make any changes to my GameViewController in regards to how I load the scene?

Comment: Yes, your code has to reflect your hierarchy, it is not magic

Comment: I managed to get it working perfectly! (so far...) Thank you so much!!! @Knight0fDragon